# c++ data type "double" how to compare irrational number?

Tags: c++

Hi I am wondering if there is good way to compare a "double" value up to some decimal places!
For example here is my code:

```
else if (choice == 2)
            {
                srand(seed);

                firstVal = (rand() % (MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE + 1)) + MIN_VALUE;
                secondVal = (rand() % (MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE + 1)) + MIN_VALUE;
                ans = firstVal / secondVal; //this part!

                cout << "Generating Values..";
                pause(3);
                cout << endl;

                cout << firstVal << endl;
                cout << secondVal << endl;

                cout << "Please enter the division of two Values(top value / bottom): ";
                cin >> userAns;

                if (userAns == ans) //This part!!
                    cout << "Congraturation. You got right answer" << endl;
                else
                    cout << "Wrong dummy!" << endl;

            }
```

I have tested some numbers. They works if there is no remainder but when it comes to decimal places, how should I compare the values???? for example if the answer comes out to be irrational number like  3.979797979797....

Comment: subtraction, and then compare to your max difference?

Comment: Sadly irrational numbers are the least of your worries. `double` (and `float`) values are imprecise, so any application of `==` is prone to failure. For example on one side you could have 10.0000000003 and on the other 9.9999999997.

Comment: All real numbers that a `double` can represent are rational.  `double`s do not use "decimal places".

Comment: irrational numbers are cool in maths, because they fill unpleasant gaps, but practically useless anywhere else. Its just impossible to measure something with infinite precision.

Comment: I like to start with Knuth's algorithms for [comparing floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/253874/4641116).  And then adjust (if needed) from there.

Comment: *"irrational number like 3.979797979797...."* -- the number you chose is the ratio of the integers `394` and `99`; it is rational by definition. In fact, one characterization of a rational number is one whose decimal representation ends with a repeating pattern of digits (such as your repeating `97`).

Comment: To more fully specify your requirements, you should give an example of your desired behavior. For example, if asking for the *quotient* of `394` and `99`, should `4` be an acceptable answer? How about `4.0` or `3.98` or `3.97980` or `3.979797979797979797979797979797979797979797979797979797979797979798`? Do you want to require a certain level of precision, or should the program adapt to the precision of the entered value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing is very important: computers don't understand the concept of irrational numbers.

In case you need to verify if a number "equals" an "irrational" number (like `sqrt(2)` or `pi`), the best thing you can do is agree on an accuracy and a way to calculate that (absolute or relative) and use that same system for the whole application.

Example: take 1E-12 as the accuracy and use relative calculation. Then, you can check a number (let's say `double d`) as follows:

```
abs((d - sqrt(2)) / sqrt(2)) <= 1E-12
```